# How do i re-render v-for loops correctly in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Short description of the project: An invoice card is to be displayed that contains information about an invoice. The user can assign payments to the invoice and also remove them. The payments are stored as an object in an array.

```
<tr class="invoice-form-wrapper invoice" v-if="item.payments.length > 0" >
     <td colspan=6>
         <template
             v-for="payment in item.payments"
             :key="payment.index"
         >
             <InvoiceForm
                  :invoiceItem="payment"
                  :calcRemainingFromInput="calcRemainingFromInput"
                  :removeForm="removeForm"
              />
         </template>
     </td>
</tr>
```

When removing a payment, the method removeForm is called which removes the object with the function filter():

```
removeForm(item) {
   for(let i = 0; i < this.invoice.invoice.length; i++) {
       let payments = this.invoice.invoice[i].payments;
       if(payments.includes(item)) {
            this.invoice.invoice[i].payments = payments.filter(obj => obj !== item);
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is that whenever the method is called, the last element disappears in the browser and not the element you want to remove. If you click on the element again, nothing happens. But when I display the array with console.log, the correct element is removed.

Does anyone have any ideas? I think Vue is not re-rendering the array correctly.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that can be run directly to see the issue?

Comment: have you `console.log`ed the array to see what the result is of your `removeForm` function?

Comment: Things like that typically happen when `:key` is not unique and stable for each item. Does `payment.index` change after removing items?

Comment: If a payments' index property is unique, I wouldn't compare the whole object in your filter function. Maybe more like `.filter(obj => obj.index !== item.index)`. This may be more of an optimization though and not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `:key="payment.index"` is wrong (index is undefined). Vue cannot map the updated data to the DOM.

You could use

```
 <template
             v-for="(payment, index) in item.payments"
             :key="index"
         >
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right, the index was the problem. I added a new randomly generated unique id and used it as the key. That solved my problem.